# Calculating characteristic function of random variable

Tags: random-variables, characteristic-functions, density-function

I would like to calculate the characteristic function of

$Z_{\beta, n}=(1-\beta^2)^{1/2}\sum_{k=0}^n\beta^kX_k$,

where $X_i$ are independent random variables with $P(X_i = 1)=P(X_i=-1) = 1/2$ 
and $\beta \in (0,1)$.

The formula would be $\phi(t) = \int_\mathbb{R}e^{itZ_{\beta,n}(x)}p_{Z_{\beta,n}}(x)dx$ where $p_{Z_{\beta,n}}$ is the density of $Z_{\beta,n}$.

I am not sure how exactly the density looks like and how to calculate the complete integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how useful my final answer here is, but by independence, one can write the characteristic function directly as

$$ \phi (t ) = E \,e^{it Z} = \prod_{k=0}^nE\, e^{is\beta^kX_k},$$
 where $s = t (1-\beta^2)^{1/2}$.

One can evaluate each term of the product explicitly:
 $$ E\,e^{is\, \beta^kX_k} = 1/2\, (e^{is\beta^k} + e^{-is\beta^k} ) =  \cos (\,s\beta^k\, ). $$ 
Therefore:

$$ \phi(t ) = \prod_{k=0}^n \cos(\, s \beta^k\,).$$

Comment: BTW, $Z=Z_{\beta,n}$ is a discrete random variable, so your  $p_Z(x)\,dx$ (in your post) is a bit problematic... No?

Comment: oops - forgive my first (not even drug induced - I'm clean - just stupidity induced) version - I had a $-$ and a $\sin$ rather than a $+$ and a  $\cos$.